# How to monitor a signal input paramater of a procedure which may dynamically change

Tags: vhdl, monitoring, test-bench

In testbench, I have an issue with a procedure that I want to monitor its input parameter which is a signal, this signal may contains a number of my internal inputs AND/OR outputs of a module/s or top level design entity. Now the problem is how can I read continually this signal which may dynamically changes.

```
 TYPE data_record IS ARRAY (natural range <>) OF STD_LOGIC;
 TYPE data_name_record IS ARRAY(natural range <>) OF STRING(1 TO 32);  

PROCEDURE MONITORING_VALUE( 
                            SIGNAL INPUTS_OUTPUT    : IN data_record ;
                            EXPECTED_VALUE          : IN data_record ;
                            INPUTS_OUTPUT_NAME      : IN data_name_record;
                            MONITORING_TIME         : IN TIME );
```

An alternative that I am using now is mapping this inputs/outputs to a signal of data_record_type :

```
SIGNAL INPUTS_ENTRED            :data_record(0 TO N-1) := ('0', '0', '0', '0');
```

===========================================================================
-- MAPPING:                                                              --===========================================================================

```
INPUTS_ENTRED(0) <= input1;
INPUTS_ENTRED(1) <= input2 ;
INPUTS_ENTRED(2) <= input3;
INPUTS_ENTRED(3) <= output1;
```

But which this solution, I am limited with number of inputs/outputs mapped which make my procedure not useful for all, (e.g. if i have 69 inputs and 9 outputs which I need to monitor a combine of them in each step).

I read about access type in vhdl, but as i have seen it's juts for variables, and i am using signal and 'last_event attribute which make impossible for me to jump to variables. and the entry parameter of the procedure is a signal.

Thanks for all. :-o

Comment: p.s. you should post a [mcve] so we know exactly what you want to do. Else we're just guessing based on the limited information you provide.

Comment: Use a signal with constant length (maximum length that can occur). Assign unused signal bits to 'U'. In your procedure, you can then loop through the signal vector and stop at the first 'U' bit.

Answer (score 1):

The INPUTS_OUTPUT signal will never change length, as it is a signal. So you can just read INPUTS_OUTPUT'length inside the procedure to see how long it is.

Comment: yes, that was what I was trying to say. Only I referenced to the wrong name. Good catch.